# SQL How to not insert duplicated values

Tags: sql, insert-update

I'm trying to create a procedure that inserts data into a table of registers but i don't want to repeat the second parameter, this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE Inscription
(
    idClass INT references tb_class,
    idStudent INT references tb_student,
)
```

The idea is that a student (`idStudent`) can register in various classes but not in the same class (`idClass`), I tried to add a unique constraint in the idStudent column but that only allows a student to register in one single class.

Comment: Add s unique constraint to a combination of the columns since that’s the unique item

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always suggest that all tables have a numeric primary key.  In addition, your foreign key references are not correct.  And what you want to do is add a unique constraint.

The exact syntax depends on the database.  The following is for SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Inscriptions (
    idInscription int identity(1, 1) primary key
    idClass int references tb_classes(idClass),
    idStudent int references tb_students(idStudnt)
    unique (idClass, idStudent)
);
```

Notice that I name the tables as the *plural* of the entity, but the id using the singular.

The `Inscriptions` table probably wants other columns as well, such as the date/time of the inscription, the method, and other related information.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to create a constraint on your table that includes both columns idClass and idStudent.

Once that constraint is created, an attempt to insert duplicate class/student will result in an error being raised.

As your table does not seem to include a primary key, you would better make that constraint your primary key.

NB : you did not tell which RDBMS you are using hence cannot give you the exact syntax to use...

Answer (score 0):

Your unique key needs to encompass both idClass and idStudent, so any particular combination cannot repeat itself.